# How do I connect Windows to Unix using public key SFTP?

Tags: sftp

I want to automate SFTP transfer between a Unix and Windows machine. I am using Bitvise Tunnelier and WinSSHD on the same machine. I used "Easy WinSSHD settings" to set the configurations. I am using virtual account settings to access the server.

First, I want to perform SFTP with username/password before trying public key authentication. When I try to connect the Windows machine to Unix (Using Putty), I'm not able to connect to the machine.

Is there a good resource that explains how to setup SFTP transfer between Unix and Windows?

Answer (score 3):

For Windows to *nix it's really hard to go past the WinSCP/PuTTY combinations, which makes this a breeze. WinSCP can be scripted for automation. There are many articles on setting up passwordless authentication. [This](http://edwardawebb.com/web-development/keys-putty-cygwin-passwordless-login-ssh-scp) is just one picked at random.

Answer (score 1):

If we exclude very little details, SFTP between Unix and Windows is exactly the same as SFTP between any system and any system. SFTP, in fact, is SSH File Transfer Protocol, and it is by all means a subsystem of the SSH protocol.

With the above in mind, PKI authentication works the same on any system that features an SSH server, and it depends on how the server is configured. Yes, it's all about the configuration. I would recommend you do the following checks:

- Make sure PKI authentication is enabled on the server side and your user's public key is accessible by the server in the right place/potision/directory
- Make sure the key-pair on the client is saved in a format that the client understands (PuTTY, for example, works flawlessly with .PPK files, but needs conversion for RSA files

My point, anyway, is: it's not a Windows/Unix issue, it's all about the configuration of your client and your server.